# Is it possible to do Role-Group based Authorization without Azure Active directory Premium

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

When RBAC was introduced in Azure Active directory, roles can be granted to users or collection of users (groups).We followed [this](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) blog post and added that functionality for our apps when it first got introduced. But now, we have to go for active directory premium to assign roles to groups and get roles in bearer token.Going with Azure Active directory is not a feasible solution for us as premium is gonna cost us $6 user/ month and we have lot of groups and each group has lot of users. Looking at the costs our IT team is not willing to go for this package. I was just wondering if there an alternative approach for mapping  roles to groups. Or this is only doable using premium.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with an Azure AD Premium or **Azure AD Basic license**, you can use groups to assign access to a SaaS application that's integrated with Azure AD( refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-manage-groups) about detail).

So if you want to manage the roles using the group, we need at least the Azure AD Basic license. If you were using the free edition, we can only **assign the roles to the users one by one**.

Instead using the role manage the access for the application, we can also use the group which also supports for the Azure AD free edition. You can check the code sample about authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Another question I have for you is, Our Active directory consists of more than 2000 users. If we go for  Azure AD Basic license do we need to buy the package for all these users or can we get licence for small set of users like 30 odd.

Comment: Also also we wanted to whether we can map **roles to group** programmatically ?

Comment: @Pickle you can programatically map roles to groups using the Azure AD Graph, specifically by a POST to appRoleAssignments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#approleassignment-entity